# My Slug Route Return 404 in my Laravel Code

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have stored my slug in my database but i get 404 Not found when i load the url

NewsController.php

```
public function show(News $news, $slug)
{   
   return view('news.single', compact('news'));
}
```

News.php

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($news) {
        $news->slug = Str::slug($news->subject);
    });
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/news/{slug}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news.show');
```

I am getting 404 not found if load e.g localhost:8000/news/sample-post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are type-hinting `News $news` in your controller method and Laravel is unable to find the correct object because 1. there's no `{news}` route parameter and 2. it's looking in the ID column by default.

There are two options to fix it:

**1. Manually load the news**

```php
public function show($slug)
{   
   $news = News::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
   return view('news.single', compact('news'));
}
```

**2. Tell Laravel to [use the `slug` column instead of `id`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/routing#route-model-binding):**

Add this method to your `News` model:

```php
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Change the route parameter name:

```php
Route::get('/news/{news}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news.show');
```

And finally, remove the `$slug` controller method parameter:

```php
public function show(News $news)
{   
   return view('news.single', compact('news'));
}
```